# What is Asperger‘s syndrome in relation to autism?

Tags: autism, aspergers-syndrome

How closely is Asperger‘s syndrome related to autism? I’m curious as I’ve got both.

Comment: What has your research found so far?

Comment: Only that Asperger’s syndrome is a variant of autism, not why a person can have both @CareyGregory

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mental health conditions are diagnosed through criteria set out in the Diagnostic and Statistical Manual of Mental Disorders (DSM) produced by the American Psychiatric Association (APA).  The current version is [DSM-5](https://www.psychiatry.org/psychiatrists/practice/dsm) and the previous version was the DSM-IV.

As you pointed out in the comments, Asperger's Disorder is a variant of Autism with a separate set of diagnostic criteria.  Because of this, Autism and Asperger's Disorder was a separate diagnosis under DSM-IV even though Asperger's Disorder is on the lower end of the autistic spectrum.

DSM-5 redefined the autism spectrum disorders expanding the **umbrella term** to encompass the previous diagnoses of autism, Asperger syndrome, pervasive developmental disorder not otherwise specified (PDD-NOS), and childhood disintegrative disorder ([APA, 2013](https://web.archive.org/web/20131006210933/http://www.dsm5.org/Documents/Autism%20Spectrum%20Disorder%20Fact%20Sheet.pdf))

> Using DSM-IV, patients could be diagnosed with four separate disorders: autistic disorder, Asperger’s disorder, childhood disintegrative disorder, or the catch-all diagnosis of pervasive developmental disorder not otherwise specified. Researchers found that these separate diagnoses were not consistently applied across different clinics and treatment centers. Anyone diagnosed with one of the four pervasive developmental disorders (PDD) from DSM-IV should still meet the criteria for ASD in DSM-5 or another, more accurate DSM-5 diagnosis. While DSM does not outline recommended treatment and services for mental disorders, determining an accurate diagnosis is a first step for a clinician in defining a treatment plan for a patient.
>
> The Neurodevelopmental Work Group, led by Susan Swedo, MD ([Swedo, et al. 2012](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22449639)), senior investigator at the National Institute of Mental Health, recommended the DSM-5 criteria for ASD to be a better reflection of the state of knowledge about autism. The Work Group believes a single umbrella disorder will improve the diagnosis of ASD without limiting the sensitivity of the criteria, or substantially changing the number of children being diagnosed.

### References

APA (2013) *Autism Spectrum Disorder Fact Sheet*. [PDF Online]
Retrieved from: https://web.archive.org/web/20131006210933/http://www.dsm5.org/Documents/Autism%20Spectrum%20Disorder%20Fact%20Sheet.pdf

Swedo, S. E., Baird, G., Cook, E. H., Happé, F. G., Harris, J. C., Kaufmann, W. E., ... & Spence, S. J. (2012). Commentary from the DSM-5 workgroup on neurodevelopmental disorders. *Journal of the American Academy of Child & Adolescent Psychiatry, 51*(4), 347-349. doi: [10.1016/j.jaac.2012.02.013](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jaac.2012.02.013) PubMed: [22449639](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22449639)

Answer (score 2):

**Asperger’s syndrome** is a condition that doctors refer to as high-functioning ASD autism spectrum disorder which impacts on the individual’s ability to read and communicate socially.

The symptoms of this condition are less severe and no such signs for language delays are observed.

I work as a sped teacher at ACCEL, and one of the major differences between children with Asperger’s syndrome and autism is that the symptoms are mildly affected and have good language.

Another distinction between Asperger’s syndrome and autism concerns cognitive ability.
Early diagnosis and treatment are important for individuals with Asperger’s syndrome to eventually live independently.

Individuals are quite reluctant towards social communication with others and show interest in specific topics.

Communication training and behavioral therapy can help people with the syndrome learn to socialize more successfully.

*References:*

*https://www.autismspeaks.org/what-asperger-syndrome*

*http://www.autism-society.org/what-is/aspergers-syndrome/*

*https://www.everydayhealth.com/aspergers/how-aspergers-different-than-autism/*

Answer (score 1):

Hans Asperger, who first reported this kind of condition, used the term "autistic psychopathy" ([DOI](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511526770.002)). From very beginning of discovery of this condition, people were aware that Aspergers is sort of autism.

Reference:

1. Asperger, H. (n.d.). “Autistic psychopathy” in childhood. Autism and Asperger Syndrome, 37–92. doi:10.1017/cbo9780511526770.002  Translated by Uta Frith
2. Wolff, S. (1996). The first account of the syndrome Asperger described? European Child & Adolescent Psychiatry, 5(3), 119–132. doi:10.1007/bf00571671 Translation of a paper entitled "Die schizoiden Psychopathien im Kindesalter" by Dr. G.E. Ssucharewa; scientific assistant, which appeared in 1926 in the Monatsschrift fur Psychiatrie und Neurologie 60:235-261